# What are viable feats for cleric in Pathfinder?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, cleric

I am having a hard time finding useful cleric feats for a more standard healing cleric.

I currently have Selective Channel, Combat Casting, Extra Channel, Quick Channel, and Divine Protection.

Are there other useful options?

I'm looking to have more options for using channel divinity charges, improve character's defense (AC and Saves), and enhance spell casting ability.  Usually there is only one to two combats per session with rests between and it lasts 3 to 4 rounds.

Comment: This question is probably too broad as worded. Can you be more specific? What do you want these feats for? If you just want a general idea of good feats versus bad feats with no other context you are better off looking up a Cleric handbook.

Comment: I added some additional information above.  Does this help?  If it is still too broad, then I can change it to simply ask for suggestions on good cleric handbooks.

Comment: This looks better, but I'm not sure what you mean by "improve my add combat diversity". Also, I don't think asking for a handbook would really be on topic for this site (it would be seen as a "shopping" question I believe) but if you Google "Pathfinder Cleric handbook" or "Pathfinder Cleric optimization" I am sure you will find at least a few useful results.

Comment: Can you link me to the "shopping" rules?  I've seen that mentioned but a formal definition would help with my education for how to use this site.  I've modified my question about the combat diversity bit, hopefully that helps.  Also I've done a bit of looking at those guides, they aren't really good at telling you want to take at levels 1 to 3.  Not that it is a problem at the moment for me but just a general observation.

Comment: If you're looking for things to take from levels 1-3, you should add that to the question too, it'll help scope things considerably.  With all build questions, take a moment to step back and put in your real actual problem with the parameters in play, it turns it from "any feat a cleric could take that they think is 'good'" (off topic) to "feats a level 1-3 cleric could take to  give more options for channeling divinity" (totally answerable).